# Concatenate all values of the same XML element using XPath/XQuery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, xml, xquery

I have an XML value like this:

```xml
<R>
  <I>A</I>
  <I>B</I>
  <I>C</I>
  ...
</R>
```

I want to concatenate all `I` values and return them as a single string: `ABC...`.

Now I know that I can shred the XML, aggregate the results back as a nodeless XML, and apply `.values('text()[1]', ...)` to the result:

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT
      n.n.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS [text()]
    FROM
      @MyXml.nodes('/R/I') AS n (n)
    FOR XML
      PATH (''),
      TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(50)')
;
```

However, I would like to do all that using XPath/XQuery methods only, something like this:

```
SELECT @MyXml. ? ( ? );
```

Is there such a way?

The reason I am looking for a solution in this direction is because my actual XML contains other elements too, for instance:

```xml
<R>
  <I>A</I>
  <I>B</I>
  <I>C</I>
  ...
  <J>X</J>
  <J>Y</J>
  <J>Z</J>
  ...
</R>
```

And I would like to be able to extract both the `I` values as a single string and the `J` values as a single string without having to use an unwieldy script for each.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
select @MyXml.value('/R[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

It picks up all `text()` elements from the first `R` and below.

If you just want all `text()` you can do

```
select @MyXml.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
```

If you want the values for `I` and `J` separate do this instead.

```
select @MyXml.query('/R/I/text()').value('.', 'varchar(50)'),
       @MyXml.query('/R/J/text()').value('.', 'varchar(50)')
```

Comment: The last one was suggested to me in chat but I find the first one extremely helpful too. I might be able to generate the XML data differently so that I can apply the first method to it.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your actual XML structure you could consider using a loop like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SELECT @xml = '<R>
  <I>A</I>
  <I>B</I>
  <I>C</I>
  <J>X</J>
  <J>Y</J>
  <J>Z</J>
</R>'

SELECT 
    Tbl.Col.query('for $i in I return $i').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    Tbl.Col.query('for $i in J return $i').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('R') Tbl(Col);
```

which outputs this:

```
(No column name) | (No column name) 
---------------  | --------------- 
ABC              | XYZ
```

See this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=17f80a9614d9d2ccfbe0b1f968fe2922)

Comment: This is really good. I can easily adapt it to include delimiters whenever I need to. And it's not too verbose to be used as it is in case I want to extract strings both with and without delimiters in a uniform way.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements and values really are short and distinct this works:

```
declare @s varchar(99) = '<R><I>A</I><I>B</I><I>C</I></R>';

select
    @s,
    REPLACE(TRANSLATE ( @s, '<>I/R', '     '), ' ', '');
```

For non-trivial XML it may struggle, though.

Comment: The elements can be short, but the values in general are not, and I can't be sure they won't contain same characters as the element names do. Appreciate the outside the box approach, though.